# $\log_{10}(ax)\cdot\log_{10}(bx)+1=0$ Provided that $ a>0;b>0$ Find the range of $b/a$ for which $x>0$ is a solution

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I'm unable to start the question.I tried graphing using desmos and found unusual activity when $0<b/a<0.92$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively: Change: $\frac ba=t \iff b=at$. Then:
$$\log_{10} (ax) \cdot \log_{10} (bx) + 1=0 \Rightarrow \log_{10}(ax)\cdot \log_{10}((ax)\cdot t)+1=0 \Rightarrow$$
$$\log_{10}(ax)\cdot [\log_{10}(ax)+\log_{10}(t)]+1=0$$

If $\log_{10}=Y$, then:
$$Y^2+\log_{10}(t)\cdot Y+1=0 \Rightarrow$$
$$D^2=\log_{10}^2 (t)-4\ge0 \Rightarrow \frac ab=t\in(0,0.01]\cup[100,+\infty).$$

Comment: Doesn't this imply $ b/a>10^{-2},b/a>10^2$ Then how does the range $(0,0.01)$ come into picture?

Comment: It is the solution of the inequality. For example, $b/a=t=0.001$ satisfies the inequality

Comment: You solve: $(\log_{10} (t)-2)(\log_{10} (t) +2)\ge 0$ and find zero points...

Comment: Sorry but what do we mean by "zero points"..

Comment: $\log_{10} (t) -2=0 \Rightarrow t=100.$ Try to find the other one yourself.

Comment: So the other value is 0.01.Do we view it as if it is a quadratic curve with roots as 0.01 and 100 giving the solution to inequality as $t\varepsilon(-\infty,0.01]\cup[100,\infty)$..

Comment: Yes, you are right. The values $0.01$ and $100$ must be included, since the inequality is not strict.

Comment: You must remember $b/a=t$ must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Call $LA=\log(a)$, $LB=\log(b)$ and $LX=\log(x)$.

Since $\log(ax)=LA+LX$ and $\log(bx)=LB+LX$ the equation is equivalent to
$$(LA+LX)(LB+LX)+1=0$$
or
$$LX^2+(LA+LB)LX+LALB+1=0$$

For this to have a real solution in $LX$ we need $$(LA+LB)-4LALB-4=(LA-LB)^2-4\geq0$$

Take into account that $LA-LB=\log(a/b)$ and you get the answer.